# Can I turn off conversation threading in sent email only?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook's conversation threading makes it really hard for me to find emails I've sent but It's useful in a normal inbox.

Is it possible to turn this feature on/off on a per-folder basis so that Sent Items shows me simply the emails I've sent in the order I sent them?

Comment: agree, threading view sucks.

Comment: @Moab I cannot figure out how it works so well in gmail and so badly in Outlook when it's basically the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the "Show as Conversion" feature in Outlook like below?

[image]

If so, as I know, we could separatly turn on/off the "Show as Conversion" for each folder in Outlook desktop client by choosing "This folder" like below.

[image]